# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null in odoo

Tags: module, odoo, typeerror

I am trying to install my custom module in odoo but every time I try to install it I get the following error. Looking for some help to resolve it.

```
Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null

http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/602-40cf611/web.assets_backend.js:498
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
    at Class.do_load_state (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/602-40cf611/web.assets_backend.js:498:56)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/602-40cf611/web.assets_backend.js:436:132)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:802:681)
    at fire (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:796:299)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:801:198)
    at Array.deferred.(anonymous function) (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:803:56)
    at fire (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:796:299)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:801:198)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:802:874)
    at fire (http://13.58.102.218:8069/web/content/596-4cc6655/web.assets_common.js:796:299)
```

Comment: There's not enough information to help you here. Can you try and run on debug mode, so the stack is a bit more clear?

Comment: And what was the problem?